# iOS: Creating admob banner and interstitial ad

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, admob, uiwindow, adbannerview

I need to have banner and interstitial within the app.

Banner should be always visible in the bottom of every screen screen, even during transitions.

Interstitial should be presented then app becomes active above full app screen.

To implement that banner, I created a new UIWindow and placed it in the bottom of the screen.
All other app (app itself, Interstitial) displayed in the big UIWindow. And in the bottom window displayed only banner, it always visible because of UIWindow.
So, to make Interstitial full screen - I make height of bottom UIWindow equal 0. And all works fine.

But, my client want that banner was always visible, that I do not hide them. How can I do it?

Comment: i don't understand this "So, to make Interstitial full screen - I make height of bottom UIWindow equal 0". why making height = 0 makes Interstitial full screen? also what's the issue with making it visible all the time? not sure if I understood what's the problem.

Comment: @TungFam, I updated question. Q: why making height = 0 makes Interstitial full screen A: Because Interstitial will be not a full screen because of bottom UIWindow. I can not present content of one UIWindow in the other. Q: also what's the issue with making it visible all the time? A: Than interstitial will be cropped at the bottom